# WebPack vendor and split points with multiple WebPack instances

Tags: webpack

I'm making a React-Redux realtime app that has multiple apps inside.

In the server, each app has its own WebPack, compiling any changes of each app.

Each app has, obviously, the react and redux libraries shared.

The thing I want to achieve is:

- Have one WebPack instance creating the common main bundle that will load any app inside. It will have the React and Redux libraries and a small piece of code doing the dynamic requires depending on user actions. This instance will not know the loaded apps names until user input.
- Have one WebPack instance per each app that is going to be required. This bundle will have the React and Redux libs discarded and only contain the required data.

I want it this way because is going to be a dynamic environment where more apps will be eventually added, so I don't want to stop/start the main instance each time to add more entry points.

How can I sync 2 WebPack instances to achieve this?

**TL;DR:**

I have this structure:
**·** main
**·** app1
**·** app2

`main` will, at some point, `require` `app1` or/and `app2` dynamically.

`main` don't knows nothing about `app1` and `app2` until user input, so I can't add them in the `main` WebPack instance.

`main`, `app1` and `app2` share some libraries, so I want them to be parsed and added to the `main` bundle but not to the `app1` and `app2` bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I have to use [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader).

Adding this to the dynamic `require` point inside `main` I get different bundles that are loaded async. I sould use a unique `WebPack` instance, but for this seems no problem.